# Running function that went from typescript->ES5->WebPack

Tags: typescript, webpack

I'm trying to run this example from cycle.js.  The docs recommend

> "We recommend the use of a bundling tool such as browserify or
>   webpack, in combination with ES6 (a.k.a. ES2015) through a transpiler
>   (e.g. Babel or TypeScript)"

So I'm transpiling from TypeScript to ES5 and then running WebPack from the command line, all with the objective of calling `runApp();`

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "es6",
    "lib": [
      "es2015",
      "es5",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "compileOnSave": true
}
```

MyScript.ts

```
import { run } from '@cycle/run';
import { makeDOMDriver, div, button } from '@cycle/dom';
function main(sources) {
    var add$ = sources.DOM
        .select('.add')
        .events('click')
        .map(function (ev) { alert('hi'); return 1; });
    var count$ = add$.fold(function (total, change) { return total + change; }, 0);
    return {
        DOM: count$.map(function (count) {
            return div('.counter', [
                'Count: ' + count,
                button('.add', 'Add')
            ]);
        })
    };
}
var drivers = {
    DOM: makeDOMDriver('.app')
};
function runApp() {
    run(main, {
        DOM: makeDOMDriver('#app')
    });
}
```

It transpiles to MyScript.js

```
import { run } from '@cycle/run';
import { makeDOMDriver, div, button } from '@cycle/dom';
function main(sources) {
    var add$ = sources.DOM
        .select('.add')
        .events('click')
        .map(function (ev) { alert('hi'); return 1; });
    var count$ = add$.fold(function (total, change) { return total + change; }, 0);
    return {
        DOM: count$.map(function (count) {
            return div('.counter', [
                'Count: ' + count,
                button('.add', 'Add')
            ]);
        })
    };
}
var drivers = {
    DOM: makeDOMDriver('.app')
};
function runApp() {
    run(main, {
        DOM: makeDOMDriver('#app')
    });
}
//# sourceMappingURL=MyScript.js.map
```

Then I run `webpack .\MyScript.js MyScriptWebPack.js`

[MyScriptWebPack.js](https://pastebin.com/BQwAfPMi)

And then I added it to my project and I have no errors, but I don't know how to call `runApp();`

Answer (score 0):

> but I don't know how to call runApp()

Your module should call `runApp` e.g.

```
function runApp() {
    run(main, {
        DOM: makeDOMDriver('#app')
    });
}
runApp(); // Start the app
```